# c# what is an efficient way to code recursive functions

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, recursion, c#-3.0

I am building a high transaction volume system that at the core has a recursive function.

In short I want to create a  spider that will take a turn and extract the URLs found in links of the page and then take each of those urls and continue to do the something. the load can get exponentially greater in a short number of cycles so I want to take great effort to make this code as streamlined and efficient as possible.

should I use threading? if so how (what’s the logic look like)

I am using the latest asp.net c# and VS2010 with .net4 and hoping that the new technology has some simple way for me to do this and hide all the complexity under the hood while processing the logic efficiently and super fast.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use recursion for a spider. You should have a task that parses a page and does whatever it is that you want to do with that page. If it finds links, it should add it to a queue of links (make sure you don't process a link more than once or you will end up with an infinite loop). The main processor would just go through the queue and process the links.

Comment: agree. but the result of the spider are visible immediately. I am not remaking google's database where i can have jobs running for hours. This will be an enter url and show results on the screen type of use. and the depth of recursion will be controlled and set to a small number like 5 (or else the web being interlinked would inevitably be an infinite loop) would you still propose your architecture?

Comment: There are always exceptions to every rule :). If you have a definite depth and are keeping track of links you've already visited, recursion might be fine, though I think using a queue isn't much more difficult (though it might be harder to keep track of depth) and would make your code more flexible. Plus it's much easier to handle threading if you have a queue to work from.

Answer (score 0):

.NET's Task Parallel Library offers a good solution for your problem. See [this MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) for more information.

The TPL is designed to accomplish parallel execution, but handle the threading for you. It also makes it easy to wait for tasks to complete, and run one task upon the completion of another set of tasks, and so on.

In your case, this would mean that a "parent" would start a task for each link in the document, and could then wait for the child tasks to complete if necessary. The child tasks could start child tasks and so on recursively. Without ever worrying about the threading.